# Late binding error

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

So i recently turned Option Strict On in my current project and after fixing all of the small errors that option throws i bumped into this one.

```
Public Sub ExportarExcel(ByVal grilla As DataGridView)

    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim j As Integer = 1
    excelApp = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
    workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add
    sheet = CType(workbook.Worksheets.Add, Excel.Worksheet)

    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In grilla.Columns
        sheet.Cells(1, i).Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous 'Problematic line
        sheet.Cells(1, i) = col.HeaderText
        i = i + 1
    Next
    i = 2

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grilla.Rows
        j = 1
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            sheet.Cells(i, j).Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous 'Problematic line
            sheet.Cells(i, j) = cell.Value
            j = j + 1
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Next

    sheet.Columns.AutoFit()
    excelApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Those two lines (from the start to "Borders.") are throwing a late binding error and i'm not sure which is the proper cast or fix for those lines.

Comment: Have you tried to use the value 1 instead of `Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous`?

Comment: @Steve  Tried, but the error points to the left side of the line "sheet.Cells(1, i).Borders"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation I found (here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822605.aspx, and here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa612949(v=office.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa612949%28v=office.10%29.aspx)), the `Borders` property returns a collection, indexed by constant that represents which border you want (top, bottom, left, right, etc.)

Your line should maybe look like this,

```
sheet.Cells(1, i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either use `sheet.Cells(i, j).Text = cell.Value` or `sheet.Cells(i, j).Value = cell.Value` (this may be Value2)